# When writing to firebase data, either reading or writing, it sends the request too many times?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, terminal, firebase-authentication

I'm currently trying to acquire/read data stored in my database on Firebase. For some reason, it is running the request too many times and I'm not sure why it's happening. (This occurs even when I'm writing where it'll input 20-30 extra slots of the same data). **Can someone tell me why this is happening and what can I do to prevent it?** 
My project is basically printing out a Family Tree connection which will eventually be used for front end. However I am dealing with a flood of information/data.
I am currently running this only on Javascript (No front end connection yet). I am using webstorm as an IDE to write this on. The following is my code:

```
export const displayFam = (user,position) => {
var relate = db.ref().child("Users").child(user).once("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(item){
        var itemVal = item.val();

        if(itemVal.mother != null){
            displayFam(user,itemVal.mother);
            console.log(itemVal.Firstname + "'s mother is " + itemVal.mother);
        }
        else{
            console.log(itemVal.Firstname + " has no mother.");
        }
        if(itemVal.father != null){
            displayFam(user,itemVal.father);
            console.log(itemVal.Firstname + "'s father is " + itemVal.father);
        }
        else{
            console.log(itemVal.Firstname + " has no father.");
        }

    });
    console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
});
```

}
This is the current data on my firebase database, where each ID is a user:

```
{
"K469jg05DnZHqn8yzp1Ucghc12n2" : [ {
    "Firstname" : "Jonathan",
    "Lastname" : "Smith",
    "father" : 1,
    "gender" : "male",
    "mother" : 2
}, {
    "Firstname" : "Patrick",
    "Lastname" : "Smith",
    "gender" : "male",
    "mother" : 3
}, {
    "Firstname" : "Lisa",
    "Lastname" : "Smith",
    "gender" : "female"
}, {
    "Firstname" : "Amelia",
    "Lastname" : "Smith",
    "gender" : "female"
} ]
}
```

This is a PART of my output:

```
Patrick's mother is 3
Patrick has no father.
Lisa has no mother.
Lisa has no father.
Amelia has no mother.
Amelia has no father.
Jonathan's mother is 2
Jonathan's father is 1
Patrick's mother is 3
Patrick has no father.
Lisa has no mother.
Lisa has no father.
Amelia has no mother.
Amelia has no father.
Jonathan's mother is 2
Jonathan's father is 1
Patrick's mother is 3
Patrick's mother is 3
Patrick has no father.
Lisa has no mother.
Lisa has no father.
Amelia has no mother.
Amelia has no father.
Jonathan's mother is 2
Jonathan's father is 1
Patrick's mother is 3
```

I expected there to be only:

```
Lisa has no mother.
Lisa has no father.
Amelia has no mother.
Amelia has no father.
Jonathan's mother is 2
Jonathan's father is 1
Patrick's mother is 3
```

I currently output everything into the terminal.